# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) .I am new to this environment and not able to figure out the error here

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-frontend

when I "npm start" I am getting this error on Safari .

> Error : Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's
> defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
>
> Check the render method of `Posts`.

How to resolve this error on VScode

**App.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { Container , AppBar, Typography , Grow , Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
    
    import Posts from './components/Posts/Posts';
    import Form from './components/Form/Form';
    import memories from './images/memories.png';
    
    
    const App = () => {
        return(
            <Container maxWidth="lg">
            <AppBar position="static" color="inherit">
              <Typography variant="h2" align="center">Memories</Typography>
              <img  src={memories} alt="icon" height="60" />
            </AppBar>
             <Grow in>
              <Container>
                <Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
                    <Posts />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                   <Form />
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Container>
            </Grow> 
          </Container>
        );
        }
    
    export default App;
```

**Posts.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Post from './Post/Post';

const Posts = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>POSTS</h1>
            <Post />
            <Post />
       </>
    );
}

export default Posts;
```

**Post.js**

```
import React from 'react';


const Post = () => {
    return (
       <h1>POST</h1>
    );
}

export default Post;
```

**Form.js**

```
import React from 'react';


const Form = () => {
    return (
       <h1>FORM</h1>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug I would suggest you that remove below code from `App.js`:

```js
import { Container , AppBar, Typography , Grow , Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
```

Remove whatever you returned from `App.js` component and use your component only.
If it works then there is a problem with your `@material-ui/core` implementation.

Also if you would like to learn in detail I would suggest you this tutorial:
[React JS tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlaA0snpxo3ycFsyxZf2Dpnznu1qCfs87)